# check null,empty or undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a project using angularjs.I have variable like

```
$scope.test = null
$scope.test = undefined
$scope.test = ""
```

I want to check all null,undefined and empty value in one condition

Answer (score 109, accepted):

just use -

```
if(!a) // if a is negative,undefined,null,empty value then...
{
    // do whatever
}
else {
    // do whatever
}
```

this works because of the == difference from === in javascript, which converts some values to "equal" values in other types to check for equality, as opposed for === which simply checks if the values equal. so basically the == operator know to convert the "", null, undefined to a false value. which is exactly what you need.

Comment: I would be careful with that when dealing with booleans. Using `$scope.$watch()` for example, you want to check if the new value is undefined or null, but if that value is a boolean, using your solution will not work.

Comment: You also want to be careful with numbers, as you may want to catch undefined and null, but not 0.

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
if($scope.test == null || $scope.test === ""){
  // null == undefined
}
```

if `false`, `0` and `NaN` can also be considered as false values you can just do

```
if($scope.test){
 //not any of the above
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($scope.test == null || $scope.test == undefined || $scope.test == "" ||    $scope.test.lenght == 0){

console.log("test is not defined");
}
else{
console.log("test is defined ",$scope.test); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's function called `angular.isUndefined(value)` returns boolean.

You may read more about angular's functions here: [AngularJS Functions (isUndefined)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined)

Answer (score 0):

> You can do simple check

```
if(!a) {
   // do something when `a` is not undefined, null, ''.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple check that you can do:

Explanation 1:

```
if (value) {
 // it will come inside
 // If value is either undefined, null or ''(empty string)
}
```

Explanation 2:

```
(!value) ? "Case 1" : "Case 2"
```

If the value is either undefined , null or '' then Case 1 
 otherwise for any other value of value Case 2.

Answer (score -2):

You can also do a simple check using function,

```
$scope.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined = function (value) {
    return !value;
}
```

Comment: The function name is misleading, since `value` might be 0.

Comment: this function will return the opposite of what you are passing. regardless of data type