# Replacements for isNullOrUndefined and isNumber utils methods after AngularJS v0.11.3 onwards

Tags: angularjs

The `isNullOrUndefined` and `isNumber` util methods have been deprecated since AngularJS v0.11.3. How can I implement these methods instead?

Comment: I believe you can use isNaN() function to check if it is a number, and for isNullOrUndefined, why just not use if(!someVariable), it will check for empty string,null,undefined.. or you need something different?

Comment: i need to check if the parameter is null or undefined. to prevent null exception error

Comment: I mean, if (!someVariable) should do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check null,empty or undefined angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124986/check-null-empty-or-undefined-angularjs)

Answer (score 5):

### Solution:

For `isNullOrUndefined` use:

```
value === undefined || value === null
```

For `isNumber` use:

```
typeof value === 'number'
```

---

Just to give a little background as to why it has been deprecated:
1. All the deprecated `util.is*()` function has some corner cases which are not covered.
2. Core modules shouldn't contain functions which are heavy or can be easily written by user. Core modules should be as light as possible.

**Example for corner cases:**
`util.isObject()` returns `false` for a function. When it should actually return `true`.